# Beamer renewcommand

Tags: beamer, macros

I am doing a presentation using the beamer class and I want to declare a new command, which shortens the following thing:

```
\textsuperscript{1}
```

to

```
\up{1}
```

I did this while using scrartcl with

```
\newcommand{\up}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
```

which is not working anymore. Can someone help me with that issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
I have to use the package

```
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```

to get \textsuperscript{1} working. It is odd that I did not have to use it while writing my report with

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
```

Can someone explain this?

Comment: If your document uses fontspec: It has removed the loading of fixltx2e, you now has to do it yourself (and do it a early as possible, e.g. with `\RequirePackage` before the  `\documentclass`.